# Pulseaudio failed to create secure directory in nfs share

Tags: permissions, configuration, opensuse, nfs, pulseaudio

My pulseaudio cannot run, because it attempts to create `~/.config/pulse` under a different user. (probably `pulse`?).

```
user@localhost ~$ pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory (/home/user/.config/pulse): Permission denied
```

Since the home directory is mounted from nfs and the server will never allow user `pulse` to access that directory (even for reading) it must either use a different path outside the home directory or run with a different user.

I have checked `/etc/pulse/client.conf`, but there doesn't seem to be any configuration option on that.

Any ideas on how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 3):

You can Change Home Directory path by editing your `/etc/passwd` file and then create home directory [using](https://serverfault.com/questions/63764/create-home-directories-after-create-users/508509#508509) :

```
/sbin/mkhomedir_helper <username> [<umask> [<skeldir>]]
```

One more thing may be `pulseaudio` is running via different user, that's why it's trying to creating file in that user home's dir so, once check using `ps -ef | grep pulse` and update in your question

Another Option :

**Run pulseaudio systemwide**

For some reasons is it a good thing to chose for a single pulseaudio daemon instead of one per logged in user

This is how you do it:

- add to every user on the system the groups 'pulse' and 'pulse-access'
- edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
- change 'daemonize = no' to 'daemonize = yes'
- change 'system-instance = no' to 'system-instance= yes'
- edit etc/default/pulseaudio
- change '`PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START=0`'  to '`PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START=1`'
- delete .pulse in your home directory and do the same fore other users
- reboot the system

[Reference Link](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1137)

Comment: Hi, I don't know what you meant with that second home directory. So I have tried to run the daemon in root. It doesn't seem to work. Also running `pulseaudio -D` in root doesn't make it work. When attempting to run pavucontrol, it hangs while attempting to connect. Also `/etc/default/pulseaudio` didn't exist, so I have created a new one. No user had a `.pulse` directory. Only `.config/pulse` so I have tried deleting that one, but it keeps coming back.

Comment: Also the user pulseaudio is running as is "pulse", but thats only if it ever gets to run without choking on that error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to give the "pulse" user the ability to write to a file inside that share. The **umask** may prevent it but if you "chmod 777 .config/pulse" the service should be able to write to it.

Comment: No, because the parent directory has no read/execute permission for pulse. Even the local root cannot access that dir.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better option (compared to running Pulseaudio systemwide) is to set a configuration location outside the NFS mount. The [Pulseaudio manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pulseaudio) explains two possibilities:

1. If a `~/.pulse/client.conf` is not found, the global `/etc/pulse/client.conf` is used (and other config files in the same directories). To use the global settings, simply delete the user-specific settings;
2. If you want per-user instead of global settings, you can set the Pulseaudio environment variable (PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG) upon login (in `.bashrc`, `.xinitrc` or using `pam_env.conf`).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I don't use setup anymore so I cannot verify this, but as far as I remember, the problem is that pulse would attempt to **create** `~/.pulse/client.conf` and choke, because it is not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

this solved the problem for me :

```
sudo chown username /home/username/.config/pulse
```